# DO the condensed photon particles-waves-longitudinal-waves exist?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, photons

This is kind of hard to explain, because weird as it sounds, i have experienced a phenomenon that i would like to see if it exists and if i can explain it mathematically.

The longitudinal waves of photons( visible light spectrum) had a density and pressure.
It could be sound waves if they can produce light effects in the space( visible,white light), i dont know  i am speculating ?.. but for this to happen, i quess, there would have to be very high frequencies of sound waves, which i quess would damage a living organism? I dont know.

I am sorry, for not being very specific, but this is everything i got.

So, my question is : Can there exist a longitudinal wave of light( white light) with density and pressure, that can be felt?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking/asking about - pure EM waves (i.e. photons) have only transverse polarizations. There are ["plasma waves"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave#Electromagnetic), among other stuff, that possess longitudinal polarizations, but these are not *waves of light*.

Answer (score 1):

Light waves cannot be longitudnal in free space.   Transverse EM waves do exert pressure, but it's too small to be perceived by humans.

Comment: I am sorry i cant describe it more exact. I am bound by my experience.. and it lasted only a  few seconds.. I felt longitudinal waves, maybe they were also transverse.. i dont know.. that is why i am asking.. the light was hitting my body and i felt pressure.. but i felt the upward motion also, that is why i thought this could be longitudinal waves..  the light(white light) had density and pressure.. is there a phenomenon in physics.. where light can have some density and pressure with which u can push or move objects?

Comment: Maybe it was not in free space.. maybe it was confined in some area.. Can light waves be longitudinal in the "cylinder space"?

Comment: If u would have plasma waves confined in "cylindrical space" and in this space u would put an object.. would this plasma waves push it in the lets say x direction? I know plasma are charged particles that fly of an "stripped atom".. and that is very energetic... but what would be the EM specter of this? Would or could it be in the visible area( 500-700nm)?  Would it be white? Because i saw it white, flickering " fluidlike raindrops", that move.. and they moved like longitudinal fashion maybe also transverse( lifting me up -upward motion) and exert pressure and had density..

Comment: If you were in air, which I assume you were :) then there was no longitudinal wave.  Sorry, I can't imagine what you experienced.

Comment: I apologize for this.. but this is the only data i have.. and i know it sounds crazy... but i am being honest and am i very curious person.. Thank you for your time, i really appreciate it!

Comment: If you saw lights, then you might have experienced "[ball lightening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning)" or one of the strange phenomena like it.

Comment: No, i know what is ball lightning.. i dont want to resolve the experience.. i just want to find out, if there is a phenomenon in physics.. where u can move objects with light densed longitudinal/transverse waves that push the object in lets say z direction( as height)?

Comment: Yes, but the pressure is very small.  Your skin or clothing would burn from the heat long before you felt the pressure.

Comment: Ok, then it was not  a plasma wave.. it was something else.. could it be sound waves. perhaps.. can high frequencies of sound change the atmosphere around and make it flicker with white light? As somekind of excitation of gas in the atmosphere? And wouldnt the high frequencies of this kind damage me, my skin .. etc..?

Comment: "Experimental evidence for Abraham pressure of light" is an article that talks about the pressure of light.